# What GUI toolkit is Cisco's ASDM written in?

Tags: java, swing, swt, awt, java-web-start

I like the way ASDM on a ASA5505 works very much. Would anyone know what GUI toolkit did Cisco use to develop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they are using quite a few JIDE components, specifically [docking](http://jidesoft.com/products/dock.htm), [tabbed pane, collapsible pane](http://jidesoft.com/products/component.htm) and [pivot grid](http://jidesoft.com/products/pivot.htm).

Answer (score 1):

It's Java Swing with an adpated look and feel. And of course some additional GUI components for docking windows, dialogs, ... Hard to see if they are custom made or licensed because ASDM is obfuscated.